# Why does "echo os.system('/bin/bash')" work?

Tags: python, echo, restricted-shell

I was doing a kind of hacking challenge, a part of which found me stuck inside a restricted shell which had very few commands. One of the available commands was `echo`. After a few hours of banging my head off the wall, I decided to peak at some hints. It turns out that `echo os.system('/bin/bash')` would break you right out of the restricted shell... it's only after I saw this that I was able to google it, but I haven't found any info on it other than that you can [do it in some](http://netsec.ws/?p=337) restricted shell situations. It doesn't work on my terminal when I tried it with zsh and bash... why does this even work? The `os.system` part looks like Python to me.. Can someone provide me with some background on it? If this is Python, how else can it be used with echo?

Comment: It does look like python, and python's `input()` function calls `eval()` on the result. I suspect that's what the vulnerability is. That's why `raw_input()` is typically recommended in python2.

Comment: sounds like an old vulnerability in LShell (restricted shell implemented in python). Also mentioned here: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Lshell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue that existed in [LShell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell/) 0.9.15, a restricted shell implemented in python.

The vulnerable function was called `check_path()`, which was used to check if a user was allowed to access the given path on the command line.

The problem was that this function used `eval()` as a mean to strip quotes from the command line, and this would happily execute any valid python expression as well.

```
        for item in line:
            # remove potential quotes
            try:
                item = eval(item)
            except:
                pass
```

This issue was later fixed in the following commit by replacing the `eval()` call with a regex substitution: https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell/commit/4e05ac2e9c12142beed0e0fa16331ee0fd7dbd42#diff-edb4dda47bc5b086988a93df2615df6f